# Move news between pages in TYPO3

Tags: typo3, tt-news

In TYPO3 version 4.7.2, I tried to change the page the particular news is assigned to, but without success. How can I do it?

Comment: Tomas, I don't want to downvote your question BUT you need to write at least what have you tried?

Comment: I actually tried @Marcus, I said it in my question. Typo3 is quite complex, so descibe my 10-step attempts would waste time and will not help anyone.

Comment: There are at least few ways to 'change the page of the news' List module, news admin, DB operations etc. I don't know what you did so don't know why it doesn't work.

Comment: @Marcus, I tried list module and news admin. In the list module, the field was greyed out - I couldn't modify it. In the news admin I can see the page number but cannot see any way to edit it.

Comment: did you try to cut it with the clipboard?

Comment: otherwise you can always edit the DB directly

Comment: @pgampe, I considered editing DB directly as a dirty hack... I could never know where is the changed value referenced, version control etc...

Comment: The page is always in `pid`. Run `update reference index` in the `db tools` module afterwards and you are fine. You should have told me that you just want to move a record ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `List` module open the page where you have the news records and make sure that `Extended view` checkbox at the bottom  is checked.

After that you'll find a scissors icon for each entry, click it, next choose the target page/folder and find the `Paste` icon (white page with green down-arrow)

If you need to copy/move more records also check the `Show clipboard` - and choose Clipboard #1 - #3

Comment: Thank you Marcus, I didin't know about the possibility of using "clipboard". Typo3 can be really tricky :-) but this is nice. Still wonder though why they don't allow me to change the "Page" field.